# How can I access the HDFS(Hadoop File System) from existing web application

Tags: java, web, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have installed hadoop 1.0.4 on my cluster, of 1 master and 3 slaves, Now I want to access my HDFS file system through my web application for storing and accessing the data for the existing web application.

As my web application currently using MySQL as a database, I want replace that by HDFS.

So what can use, so that I am able to access HDFS by existing web application?

For backend data migration purpose I am using sqoop and flume but I want the real time application synchronization with HDFS. As what I saved from web-page should directly go to the HDFS and what I want search should directly come from HDFS.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you migrate from mysql to hadoop ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response kirugan, As my data getting increased day by day and of different type like structured(user data) and unstructured(songs,videos) and I also want to implement the display recommendation functionality.

Comment: Hm... you want to use something like Apache Mahaout ?

Comment: Yeah I have already Integrated that for display recommendation purpose but I want how to integrate it with real time app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like replacing an apple with an orange.

You can't replace MySQL with HDFS. MySQL is a database while HDFS is a file system like ext3/ext4. HDFS operates in a distribued fashion while ext3/ext4 won't.

HDFS provides high latency and high throughput, while a MySQL database provides low latency and low throughput. Think of replacing a RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle etc) with a NoSQL DB (Cassandra, HBase etc).

There are tons of NoSQL databases, based on the requirement analysis the appropriate one has to be chosen.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but that is what I have a HBase configured with Hadoop which a hadoopDB, so how can I access it through a normal web application, can I access it through JDBC?

Comment: HBase can be accessed from Command Line and also using the Java API. Check the HBase documentation (http://hbase.apache.org/book.html) for the same. An SQL layer was added to HBase recently (http://phoenix-hbase.blogspot.in/).